# Problem with internal linking after website migration to GCP

Tags: html, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

So, I have migrated my websites to Google Cloud Platform, and that works fine, most of it. But, some links have some issues with the permalink format. For example, I have an internal link to my other page and the link is something like mywebsite.com/some-page, but for some reason after migrating some links turned to mywebsite.com/some-page/some-page/. I check the HTML code, and it looks fine. Here's an example page:

https://sewingmachinelife.com/learn-how-to-sew-different-clothing-materials/

Near the bottom you have these 2 internal links:

[image]

If you click them you'll see that one of them is fine, and one of them is not. I have this issue with 3 more websites migrated to GCP. Any ideas why this happened?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<h3>Silk and Satin</h3>
<a href="https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-silk">Silk</a> and <a href="https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-satin-fabric/">satin</a> are materials made for perfect elegant dresses, skirts, blouses, or exclusive bed sheets.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem now:

Both links contain a category name (/beginner-info/) in the link target URL:

`https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-silk`
and
`https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-satin-fabric`

This is not a valid url, because your permalink structure is currently set to `Post Name` and not to:

`/%category%/%postname%/`

So what happens is that WordPress tries to find the correct item via the slug and redirects to it:

**Satin** gets correctly redirected to the right place (same url without the category) because it has a unique slug.

**Silk** on the other hand share a slug with an attachment (image) and gets redirected there (that's why you see the slug twice - note the attachment name)

To solve all this you will either need to change the Permalink structure one last time to Custom Structure -> `/%category%/%postname%/`

OR

You can remove the category from all the links in your content (e.g. replace every `sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/` to `sewingmachinelife.com/` (You'll need to do that for all categories)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I still get the 404 error when I try it directly in this browser, probably a cache issue, but when I try it in the incognito mode it's good. Can you just explain to me why this happened to all my websites after the migration? I cloned the websites and just restored them on my new hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh the WordPress permalinks after the migration?
Go to Dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks and under 'Common Settings' - note the current selection and then select 'Plain' and save changes.

You then revert back to your original permalink structure of choice - this usually resolves such problems (don't forget to also clear the cache if your using a cache plugin)

Comment: Yeah, I did that twice. Tried changing and reverting back, but no luck. I even tried deleting that paragraph and adding it again, but still the same. I don't understand why 2 of the same links, but to different articles, act differently?!

Comment: Actually, it's not the same, but the problem is still here, but in a different form. When I change it to plain, now when you click on my link about it drives to my home page.

Comment: And when I select Numeric or Month and name, it's OK. But I don't want that. I want Post name.

Comment: And when I select Custom structure: /%post_id%/%postname%/ it's OK, but I only get the numbered post ID in the URL, which I also don't want.

Comment: The problem is not with the links, it's most likely a redirect problem, when put this link: https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-silk in the browser I get the same issue - so i think it gets redirected incorrectly.

What happens if you set permalinks to plain? Does the links resolve correctly?

Comment: And the weird thing is, when I try to revert it back to the post name, I get Error 404 when I click the link above. :/

Comment: Hillel, No. Check my replies above. I described several scenarios.

Comment: But how?! When I click the link (in several browsers) it takes me to my home page. Can you try again please?

Comment: I see what's happening, you've set the permalinks to plain like i suggested. What you're seeing is the expected behavior: your original post is now here: https://sewingmachinelife.com/?p=574 and the linked urls are no longer valid (the new urls are https://sewingmachinelife.com/?p=459 and https://sewingmachinelife.com/?p=462) the links are part of the content and were not updated. is 'beginner-info' a category/taxonomy or is it your posts page?

Comment: It's a category.

Comment: what happens if you change the permalinks structure back to Post Name now?

Comment: I get a 404 error. I will change it now and you can check it out when you see my message.

Comment: I think I got it, both links contain a category name in the url: https://sewingmachinelife.com/beginner-info/10-tips-for-sewing-with-silk

Comment: Yes they do. So, what about it? That should be a normal thing, right? So how can I fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228461/discussion-between-hillel-and-user2083882).